# What do you think of this recent (unfinished) bathroom tiling work?

Tags: bathroom, tiling

We recently hired a contractor via a 3rd party bidding website for such projects.

There are several obvious mistakes or oversights here.
We've already allowed the contractor to correct some of his mistakes, but at this point we are convinced he is not experienced enough to do the job if even we gave him multiple chances to fix things.

Job details:

- The contract says we need a $2000 deposit upfront to get the project
  started and for materials/supplies.
- The 2nd half of the payment would be $2700 upon completion.

> Please see these photos and tell me my frustrations are either justified
>   or i'm just being picky. Keep in mind that the project is not complete.

Below: Corner edging for the niche.
[image]

Below: Ceramic floor tiles were cut to fit around the toilet (several tiles were destroyed in the process).
[image]

Below: Caulking in the niche.
[image]

Below: Noticeably uneven tile job (i.e. lippage?).
[image]

Below: Grout + caulking around the shower floor-pan edge is already cracking. Note that the edge here had large gaps between the floor-pan and the floor tiles. The contractor explained that he caulked it before the grout dried.
[image]

Below: New molding for floor/wall corner.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Below: Edge of wall tiles is very uneven (the higher you go up the more it leans to the left).
[image]

Note: I'm now aware that the wall/floor moulding may not be an issue as the contractor may have had something like this in [mind](https://www.google.com/search?q=floor%20moulding&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiiidOy2PfTAhUO_mMKHcwgBbUQ_AUIBygC&biw=1280&bih=906#imgrc=ES4YSXBdLclV8M:&spf=1495050310112).

Comment: You are not being picky.  it is very amateurish work, unacceptable and not to be expected from a professional. He did not even know to take the toilet up and tile under it.   We can not give legal advise. you need to read the contract or legal info on the site you hired him on. You may need a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll take it into deep consideration.

Comment: My condolences. However, this entire question is off topic as either legal or opinion-based. Best of luck.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar see my answer - you are not being too picky,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work is shoddy.

- Toilet should have been lifted and tiled under.
- 2 x 4's for molding.
- Inset opening - no Bull nose tiles on the inset.
- Bad molding.
- poor fit.
- Plenty of other things here .

Directly to your questions and concerns ..

In your contract you paid 2K up front. 
Look at your contract READ it.

You should with hold

- The 2nd half of the payment $2700 upon completion.

It says upon Completion. Hope you paid the first half with a Credit
   Card.

- The job is not complete - it is not properly or satisfactorily performed.
- Get Free advice from an Attorney or spend $200 to discuss it with an Attorney. $200 is cheaper than $2700 and a bad tile job.

***Disclaimer:***

*I am not an attorney and this does not constitute legal advice and is not a substitute for legal advice.*

**For those who decide to do this kind of selection of a contractor to perform work:**

- Get references,
- Talk to those references.
- View the results if possible (not pictures unless the references are providing them.
- Pay with a Credit Card if you can as there is more recourse to get the issue resolved or your money back in the event you have an issue.

Comment: We are definitely not paying the remaining half. We paid the up-front cost with a personal check.

Comment: Sue in small claims court for the $2000 you did spend, you could easily argue that a competent professional will have to rip it all out and do it all over the right way (get some bids). Court systems generally rule according to how an average reasonable person would feel about the issue.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - he might be able to get that, he is better to get an attorney - the case will go to small claims regardless, under $5000 is generally the threshold for states. The quality of work and expectations are probably not specified in the contract. The fact that it is tiled and the contractor did attempt to fix the errors; will factor in favor of the contractor. He should consult an attorney, $2000 to the contractor or the attorney depending on if he gets win and fees. A Judgment does not guarantee payment either, he could be out $4000 with a collection notice out on the contractor.

Comment: There is an industry body that has definitions of what's acceptable, the Tile Council of North America, here - http://www.tcnatile.com/ 
If you do wind up going to court as some commentators are suggestion, the Tile Council has a publication on acceptable standards for tile installations.