# Is grout in the toilet a plumbing clog concern?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, grout, clog

I recently had a bathroom tiling job gone bad. There were a number of [issues](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114876/need-your-opinion-on-a-recent-unfinished-bathroom-tiling-work). One thing I noticed this morning was that the bottom of the toilet has what appears to be dried up grout mixture. Fortunately it doesn't appear to be hard/stuck (I poked it with a pencil and found that its like silt/sand).

Could this still be a plumbing problem, if not now then possibly later?

Below: This is what I noticed at the bottom this morning.
[image]

Below: After I poked it around with a pencil.
[image]

Comment: Did a contractor tile your bathroom and dump the excess down the toilet? Do you have a water well that sometimes causes sand build up? Is there any sand in your tank?

Comment: @cutrightjm - Judging by the tiling job in the OP's previous question, it wouldn't surprise me if the tiling contractor tried to flush his excess grout ...

Comment: It's likely the remains of the grout removal sponge rinse bucket.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar hope you flag that contractors site, links or page somewhere - where are you in the world  ? if in the USA make sure you flag the BBB , Yelp, Angies .. at least you will spare someone

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely to be a problem. The cement in the mortar is diluted enough that it won't create a plug downstream. You're mostly looking at clean silica sand. However, I'd play it safe and vacuum it out before flushing.

I'd then disallow that contractor from entering my home ever again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove as much as you can, manually.

If the toilet flushes properly at this time, then it is not likely that any permanent damage has been done. Basically what you are hoping is that grout did not "set up" in either the toilet trap or downstream somewhere. Your tile contractor was a jackass.

Comment: I think I need to manually remove it. I noticed that when I flushed the first couple of times all the silt stayed at the bottom (seems to hardly move, though it was hard to tell due to the flowing water).